# Exclude specific calculation from subtotal and grand total lines

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have this table :

[image]

And I want to calculate for each day and for each group `1and2 %` which is

```
(Attribute1/Attribute2)*100
```

But I don't want to include `1and2 %` in Group Subtotal neither on total

I created a new table :

```
Table3 = UNION(DISTINCT('Table'[Attributes]);{{"1and2 %"}})
```

And i made this mesure to calculate `1and2 %`:

```
Measure =
SUMX (
    DISTINCT ( 'Table3'[Attributes] );
    SWITCH (
        'Table3'[Attributes];
        "1and2 %"; DIVIDE (
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ); 'Table'[Attributes] = "Attribute1" );
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ); 'Table'[Attributes] = "Attribute2" );
            0
        ) * 100;
        VAR a = 'Table3'[Attributes]
        RETURN
            CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ); 'Table'[Attributes] = a )
    )
)
```

And this is the result I'm getting :

[image]

I want to exclude `1and2 %` (and every Attribute containing % in the future) from group subtotal and the total.

I'm really new to PowerBI and not really familiar with Excel-like formulas.
Can anyone please help me up with that?

Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone from PowerBI forum gave me this solution and it's exactly what im looking for:

Create another mesure using the existing :

```
Measure 2 =
VAR __Table =
  ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
      'Table 3',
      [Group],
      [Attribute],
      "__Measure",[Measure]
    ),
    "__IncludeInTotals",SEARCH("%",[Attribute],,-1)
  )
RETURN
  IF(
    HASONEVALUE('Table 3'[Attribute]),
    [Measure],
    SUMX(FILTER(__Table,[__IncludeInTotals] = -1),[__Measure])
  )
```

Comment: This appears to work but is more complicated and less efficient than what I suggested and requires building a second measure that is also more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @AlexisOlson you didn't really answer to the "and every Attribute containing % in the future" part, it may be more complicated but it does the job and i don't need to do refactoring of what i wrote to work

Comment: You can simply change `SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table3'[Attributes] ) = "1and2 %"` to `CONTIANSSTRING ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table3'[Attributes] ), "%" )` in that case.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can get what you want if you only calculate the `1and2 %` part when that's the only thing in the filter context and do a normal sum otherwise.

```
Measure =
IF (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table3'[Attributes] ) = "1and2 %";
    DIVIDE (
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ); 'Table'[Attributes] = "Attribute1" );
        CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ); 'Table'[Attributes] = "Attribute2" );
        0
    ) * 100;
    SUM ( 'Table'[Value] )
)
```

For the subtotals and grand total, `SELECTEDVALUE` returns blank so the condition fails and you just get the sum.

Comment: Isn't that what im doing right now just written with a IF instead of a Switch?

Comment: Nope. You're forcing it to iterate over all of the `Table3[Attributes]` with the `SUMX`.

Comment: I found another solution, check post below in few mins